Kibana Rule API - export from cluster with API
I am trying to pull rules which are created in our elastic cluster.
I have used below API query , to get all the alert names.
GET kbn:/api/alerting/rules/_find
The need i am looking for is to export this all alert names to excel. Any possibility to export rules from cluster with API?
Tried rul api to list all the alerts:
Get kbn:/api/alerting/rules/_find
Expecting result can export to excel ?

You can use Python and libraries like requests to interact with the Elasticsearch API and pandas to create and save the Excel file.
